# ul Class line-style not working, in any form

Tags: css, html-lists

I have an unordered list, with a css class tag attached to it, every attribute attached to this class with CSS works, EXCEPT the "list-style" attribute. (Basically i'm trying to get bullet points using my own image, a very simple task usually, but currently it really is not.

**HTML** Code:

```
<ul class="bullets">
    <li>The prices abo...</li>
    <br>
    <br>
    <li>The above t...</li>
    <br>
    <br>
    <li>If you wish ...</li>
    <br>
    <br>
    <li>Price is also depe...</li>
    <br>
    <br>
    <li>A white underb...</li>
    <br>
    <br>
    <li>If you w...</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS** Code:

```
ul.bullets li {
    font-size:12px;
    font-family:"Tw Cen MT";
    color:#000000;
    list-style:url('../images/bulleta.png');
}
```

As i say, every attribute within the CSS class works fine, except the `list-style:url('bulleta.png');` attribute, the image is loaded onto the server, so not sure why it won't work, i've tried just attaching the class to the ul and also to the ul's list.

Anyone see where i'm wrong? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work fine. See **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6phG8/).**
Make sure that you have indented the `ul` enough to see the images (uncomment line to see effect).

CSS:

```
ul
{
    //margin-left:100px;    
}
ul.bullets li
{
   font-size:12px;
   font-family:"Tw Cen MT";
   color:#000000;
   list-style:url('src');
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="bullets">
    <li>The prices abo...</li>
    <br><br>
    <li>The above t...</li>
    <br><br>
    <li>If you wish ...</li>
    <br><br>
    <li>Price is also depe...</li>
    <br><br>
    <li>A white underb...</li>
    <br><br>
    <li>If you w...</li>
</ul>
```

You may also want to look at the network tab (first bring up the dev tools, normally <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd>) in the browser to make sure that the image is actually being retrieved.

**Update**

Based on the link you sent, I can see what is happening, `media='all'` is overriding the display of list-item.

Note that the `media=all` display is overriding the list-item. When I unselect this style, your images appear.

[image]

As a simple solution you can just add `display:list-item;` to `ul.bullets li`. CSS will use the most specified.

Comment: For some reason the image still won't display, i also tried simply "list-style:circle", also didn't work. When i move the margin to the left, it only moves the first line of the list, not the entire list.

I've had a look through my CSS and can't see any 'overriding' CSS.

http://www.crookedcartoon.co.uk/print.html#pricing

Is the site.

Comment: can't see on your site where you are trying to use `<ul class="bullets">`

Comment: Thankyou Acarlon, let me have a look through my CSS now, i haven't noticed that, but my last notion would be i'd have some hidden CSS overriding my li attributes.

Comment: @user3494604 - Sounds good. I have added an image to show it more clearly.

Comment: I see the li
{
display:inline;
}
attribute, but i don't see how i can remedy this situation without changing a lot of my code to specify certain li classes.. shit.

Comment: Is there anyway i can override that media all li class attribute in this one li class?

Comment: @user3494604 As a simple solution you can just add `display:list-item;` to `ul.bullets li`. CSS will use the most specified.

Comment: Thankyou, yeah great solution. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem in your code else that the image source of the list style is broken. You have to check it again. [This is a jsbin demo](http://jsbin.com/dakapeja/1/) exactly typical your code except the url of the image:

Comment: It was a "media all" issue, as in i had another bit of CSS targeting all li items, therefore overriding the CSS i had for this.
Thanks though.